# IMDB API - Retrieve all movies from a list?

Tags: imdb

I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve all the movies from a list (this one for example : https://www.imdb.com/list/ls052535080/) via an API ?

I see nothing for this kind of use.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I would suggest you to check the Movie Db https://www.themoviedb.org/

Comment: Movie Db has a complete API that's right, but unfortunately, i'm trying to retrieve the 1001 Movies You Must See Before You Die, and there is no such list like that on TMDB

Comment: As far as I know IMDB has no API that let you do that directly.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `export` word to the end of the list url, it'll be `https://www.imdb.com/list/ls052535080/export`

Answer (score 1):

No API needed for this. All lists have an export function which will provide the entire list as a csv file containing a variety of fields:

- Position, Const, Created, Modified, Description, Title, URL, Title Type, IMDb Rating, Runtime (mins), Year, Genres, Num Votes, Release Date, Directors, Your Rating, Date Rated

Simply open up the list page ie: /list/ls#########/, click the vertical ellipsis menu button at the top right of the page:

[image: example screenshot of ellipsis menu button]

Then click the "Export" link in the popup menu:

[image: example screenshot of popup menu with export option highlighted]

You'll be prompted with a csv file that has a filename based on the list name.

Answer (score 0):

IMDB does not have any API as such. 
This could help (web scraping) --

```
import requests
import browsercookie
import bs4
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/user/ur<user_id>/lists?ref_=nv_usr_lst_3'
cj = browsercookie.chrome()
res = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
```